# Cannot get coordinates after dragging image using KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I am using KineticJS and I want to get the x,y coords of a dragged image.  I have the following code but the dragend event doesn't appear to be firing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
   var myim = new Kinetic.Image({
   x: 50,
   y: 50,
   image: imageObj,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   draggable: true
   });

layer.add(myim);
stage.add(layer);   
};

imageObj.src = 'myimage.png';

myim.on("dragend", function() {
   var points = myim.getPosition();
   alert(points.x + ',' + points.y);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the event handler inside the `imageObj.onload` function because `myim` is in the scope of this function and thus, it cannot be resolved outside this function to attach the event handler.